# Any way to do a path expression that evaluates to a left join in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

This JPQL query:

```
select p from Post p where p.status = 'public' or p.author.name = 'John'
```

Translates to a `join` between `post` and `author`, so it misses all records that are public (`status = 'public'`) that has no author (`author = null`).

Any way to convert this to a left join, without adding an explicit left join clause to the "from" part?

I can't do an explicit left join on the "from" part like this:

```
select p from Post p left join p.author a where p.status = 'public' or a.name = 'John'
```

Because the code that generates the `p.author.name = 'John'` clause has no way to add a new relation to the "from" part.

So, this part is static, I can only append clauses to it:

```
select p from Post p where p.status = 'public'
```

Comment: you mean like explicitly saying "LEFT OUTER JOIN p.author" in the FROM part of the query? Any JPQL documentation would show how to do that.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do a left join without saying it explicitly in the from part of the query. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: you cannot. That is what the FROM clause is for. Putting stuff in the WHERE will get what the JPA provider gives you ..

Comment: you might look at building your query using CriteriaBuilder rather then a JPQL string, as it is easier to build onto dynamically.

Comment: I can't use CriteriaBuilder, I'm typing this clause into `@AdditionalCriteria` form Eclipselink, it only accepts JPQL.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in JPQL, and though you could use a subquery to avoid the join in the inner query, I don't know how it would work within @AdditionalCriteria.

If you need to add an outer join in additional criteria, you will need to use native EclipseLink API, setting an outerjoin expression through a descriptor customizer.  This [blog](http://java-persistence.blogspot.com/2010/08/eclipselink-filters-how-to.html) gives an example, while EclipseLink's expression framework does outer joins using the getAllowingNull as described in the documentation [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/concepts/expressions002.htm#CJAIJIIF)